# Loading resources before running java code in servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a servlet in tomcat. It takes a really long time for the java code in the backend to execute. Is there a way to load static resources (css,images,javascript) in parallel with the code in the backend? Right now, they are only loaded once the code finishes running.

Comment: Have you consider using ajax on this?  eg. load the page, make one ajax request for the heavy stuff and callback to the user when it's done.

Comment: also using ajax you have the option to load your data piece by piece. Call ajax to load content on div 1, and when finishes loading load content on div 2 etc... thus making your application more interactive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an Ajax-style solution where you paint your page without data, with a placeholder for retrieving the data, maybe even with a "loading" spinner graphic.

The way that an Ajax call works, when the page is loaded, some Javascript will fire that will launch an Ajax request to Tomcat via XmlHttpRequest that will start the calculation. The browser will notify the browser when the tomcat request is completed. Then there will be some javascript in the webpage that will take the response and replace the placeholder. If the server returns an HTML fragment, it's as simple as executing in javascript *placeholder-div*.innerHtml = *your-response-text*.

Here's a [basic tutorial on Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) and a [Java-based example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-ajax1/) that has the web front-end communicating with a Java Servlet back-end.

Comment: definitely recommend Ajax too